# Plain Javascript Equivalent of jQuery.param()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) takes an array of key-value pairs, and turns it into a string you can use as a query string in HTML requests. For example,

```
a = {
      userid:1,
      gender:male
    }
```

would get converted to

```
userid=1&gender=male
```

I'm trying to call external APIs on the server side in a Google Apps script, which need long query strings. I would use the jQuery param function, but there seems to be no easy way to use jQuery on the server side in Google.

Could you give me plain javascript code that achieves the same functionality?

The jQuery implementation of it is [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2e10af143b7eafb7142524f6534a62aee1910bd1/src/ajax.js#L507), but I don't want to take chances skipping over any crucial details by simply copying it and ripping out the code dealing with 'traditional'.

Comment: I found this to be a great solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-param

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can also do that with pure JavaScript, but you have to write more lines of code. Try this:

```js
a = {
      userid:1,
      gender: "male",
    }

url = Object.keys(a).map(function(k) {
    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(a[k])
}).join('&')

console.log(url)
```

The output is this:

```
userid=1&gender=male
```

Comment: Thanks Amynut. That's what I thought it would be, but wanted to make sure I don't miss any subtleties and do it in the most JSic (to Javascript what Pythonic is to Python) way.

One subtlety in the jquery implementation is "return s.join("&").replace(r20, "+");". Do you not need actually need that replacement with + signs? MDN suggests that this is relevant when POSTing rather than GETting. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description

Comment: how about nested keys ? you'll need recursion or flatten the object.

Comment: worth mentioning that it does not support arrays/objects. `{a:[1,2],b:{c:3}}` should convert to `a[]=1&a[]=2&b[c]=3` and not `a=1,2&b=[object Object]`

Answer (score 4):

ES6 version that allows to convert nested objects and arrays just use like `encodeURI(getUrlString({a: 1, b: [true, 12.3, "string"]}))`.

```
getUrlString (params, keys = [], isArray = false) {
  const p = Object.keys(params).map(key => {
    let val = params[key]

    if ("[object Object]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(val) || Array.isArray(val)) {
      if (Array.isArray(params)) {
        keys.push("")
      } else {
        keys.push(key)
      }
      return getUrlString(val, keys, Array.isArray(val))
    } else {
      let tKey = key

      if (keys.length > 0) {
        const tKeys = isArray ? keys : [...keys, key]
        tKey = tKeys.reduce((str, k) => { return "" === str ? k : `${str}[${k}]` }, "")
      }
      if (isArray) {
        return `${ tKey }[]=${ val }`
      } else {
        return `${ tKey }=${ val }`
      }

    }
  }).join('&')

  keys.pop()
  return p
}
```

Answer (score 2):

most solutions here fail on array/object values.

this will support arrays/objects of the first level:

```
const param = obj => Object.entries(obj).map(
    pair => Array.isArray(pair[1]) ?
        pair[1].map(x=>`${encodeURIComponent(pair[0])}[]=${encodeURIComponent(x)}`).join('&') :
        typeof pair[1] === 'object' ? 
        Object.entries(pair[1]).map(x=>`${encodeURIComponent(pair[0])}[${x[0]}]=${encodeURIComponent(x[1])}`).join('&') :
        pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('=')).join('&')
```

examples:

```
param({a:1,b:'b'})
"a=1&b=b"

param({a:1,b:2,c:[1,2],d:{e:'abc',f:4}});
"a=1&b=2&c[]=1&c[]=2&d[e]=abc&d[f]=4"

param({a:1,b:2,c:[1,2,'"'],d:{e:'a"b[c]',f:4}});
"a=1&b=2&c[]=1&c[]=2&c[]=%22&d[e]=a%22b%5Bc%5D&d[f]=4"
```

however, note that it fails on 2nd level (nesting):

```
param({a:1,b:{c:[1,2]}});
"a=1&b[c]=1%2C2"
```

**UPDATE:**

if you don't need IE11 support please use the `URLSearchParams` API. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48327251/3356679) by `error`:

```
function urlString(params)
{
    if (!params)
        return '';
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
    for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(params))
        urlParams.append(name, value || '');
    return urlParams.toString();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@Amaynut's answer is awesome. But I do some simplify:

```
const obj = {
  userid: 1,
  gender: 'male'
}

const params = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[k])).join('&')
```

or maybe modulize it using es6 module:

util.js

```
export default {
  params (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map((k) => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[k])).join('&')
  }
}
```

and use like this:

```
import util from './util'

const q = {
  userid: 1,
  gender: 'male'
}

const query = util.params(q)

console.log(query)
```

Comment: Or `Object.entries(obj).map(pair => pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('=')).join('&')`

Comment: awesome @Albin, but beware compatibility of these es's new feature, good luck:-D

Comment: Sure! Use polyfills for compatibility. Polyfill.io for example takes care of that.

Comment: Thank you for the variation. I find @amaynut's code easier to read. IMO a one-liner doesn't always indicate simplification.

Comment: worth mentioning that it does not support arrays/objects. `{a:[1,2],b:{c:3}}` should convert to `a[]=1&a[]=2&b[c]=3` and not `a=1,2&b=[object Object]`

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support  import.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version of the `URLSearchParams` answer from @oriadam / @error, with support for multi-level nesting:

```js
const urlString = (data) => {
    if (data == null) { return ""; }
    
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
    const rbracket = /\[\]$/;

    const add = (name, valueOrFunction) => {
        const value = typeof valueOrFunction === "function" ? valueOrFunction() : valueOrFunction;
        urlParams.append(name, value == null ? "" : value);
    };

    const buildParams = (prefix, obj) => {
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            obj.forEach((value, index) => {
                if (rbracket.test(prefix)) {
                    add(prefix, value);
                } else {
                    const i = typeof value === "object" && value != null ? index : "";
                    buildParams(`${prefix}[${i}]`, value);
                }
            });
        } else if (typeof obj === "object" && obj != null) {
            for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
                buildParams(`${prefix}[${name}]`, value);
            }
        } else {
            add(prefix, obj);
        }
    };

    if (Array.isArray(data) || data instanceof NodeList) {
        // If an array or NodeList was passed in, 
        // assume that it is a collection of form elements:
        data.forEach(el => add(el.name, el.value));
    } else {
        for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(data)) { 
            buildParams(name, value);
        }
    }

    return urlParams.toString();
};
```

This is based on [the jQuery 3.5.1 source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/serialize.js), so it should produce identical outputs to `$.param` for the same inputs. The only difference is that spaces will be encoded as `+` instead of `%20`.

I've provided [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardD/kx7q1y3b/) using [the jQuery test cases](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/test/unit/serialize.js), all of which pass.

---

**Edit:** If you need to support an environment without support for the `URLSearchParams` class, you'll need to use a combination of an array and the `encodeURIComponent` method, as shown in the other answers:

```js
const urlString = (data) => {
    if (data == null) { return ""; }
    
    const urlParams = [];
    const rbracket = /\[\]$/;

    const add = (name, valueOrFunction) => {
        let value = typeof valueOrFunction === "function" ? valueOrFunction() : valueOrFunction;
        if (value == null) { value = ""; }

        urlParams.push(`${encodeURIComponent(name)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`);
    };

    const buildParams = (prefix, obj) => {
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            obj.forEach((value, index) => {
                if (rbracket.test(prefix)) {
                    add(prefix, value);
                } else {
                    const i = typeof value === "object" && value != null ? index : "";
                    buildParams(`${prefix}[${i}]`, value);
                }
            });
        } else if (typeof obj === "object" && obj != null) {
            for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
                buildParams(`${prefix}[${name}]`, value);
            }
        } else {
            add(prefix, obj);
        }
    };

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        // If an array was passed in, 
        // assume that it is a collection of form elements:
        data.forEach(el => add(el.name, el.value));
    } else {
        for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(data)) { 
            buildParams(name, value);
        }
    }

    return urlParams.join("&");
};
```

[Updated test Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardD/kx7q1y3b/1/)

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support `NodeList`.

Comment: `URLSearchParams` isn't supported either.

Comment: @Rubén Well, that sucks. At least it's easy to remove the `NodeList` reference and replace the `URLSearchParams` with an array - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and update Richard. While it's not strictly necessary, it might be good to test the code on Google Apps Script because it the OP's target platform. Have you already done this? P.S. Please consider that questions and answers have a version history. Considering this, I think that there is no need to label a section as "edit" (there is a discussion about this on [meta]).

Answer (score 0):

```
ES6 gives us some nice primitives:

    // Function that parses an object of string key/value params to build up
    // a string of url params
    // requires an object with no nested values
    export function parseUrlParams(urlParams) {
        const joinByEquals = (pair) => pair.join('=')
        const params = Object.entries(urlParams).map(joinByEquals).join('&')
        if (params) {
            return `?${params}`
        } else {
        return ''
        }
    }
```

See it in action here:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KnpOI6hb1AzTDpN3wS7

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support `export`.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit frustrating. None of the solutions here seemed to actually work to produce actual "x-www-form-urlencoded" data for any JSON object, the equivalent of JQuery. Some came close but failed on child items. I pieced code from a few of the solutions to get this, working version for any JSON object:

```
function formData (obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map((k) => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj[k]))).join('&')
}
```

FYI I had to use this for FastSpring's API, because for some freaky reason they only accept x-www-form-urlencoded data in 2020. Spent all day on this because this is the first time in almost a decade an API didn't just accept JSON :(

Answer (score -1):

```js
export function param( params ) {
    const p = new URLSearchParams;
    for( const [ key, value ] of Object.entries( params ) ) {
        p.set( key, String( value ) );
    }
    return p.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how the above code helps.

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support `export`.