# Encode object literal as URL query string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, query-string

I am trying to get rid of the jQuery dependency in a project. One thing that project does is posting data to a server like so:

```
var data = {"apple": [{"kiwi": "orange"}, {"banana": "lemon"}], "pear": "passion fruit"};
$.post( url, data);
```

Thanks to [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post), I know how to rewrite `$.post` in pure Javascript using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open( 'POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send( data);
```

Unfortunately, this description seems to assume that the `data` object is already a URL-encoded query string, which is clearly not the case in the above example. It turns out jQuery does more than that: With the given `data` object, the above `$.post` call would first convert it to a query string, which would look like so:

```
apple%5B0%5D%5Bkiwi%5D=orange&apple%5B1%5D%5Bbanana%5D=lemon&pear=passion+fruit
```

The code snippet using `XMLHttpRequest` does not do so, and, thus, the server will throw errors at me.

jQuery also has a wonderful method call [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) which does exactly this conversion. The above code snippet using `XMLHttpRequest` will work marvelously if in the last line I do

```
request.send( $.param(data));
```

But then, I did not get rid of the jQuery dependency. So I'm looking for a pure Javascript equivalent of `$.param`. Does anyone have something like that?

**Note:** The question [Plain Javascript Equivalent of jQuery.param()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224887/plain-javascript-equivalent-of-jquery-param) asks a similar question, but the accepted answer only works in very simple cases. Applying the function given in that answer to my above `data` object yields:

```
apple=%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D&pear=passion%20fruit
```

...which is obviously different from the result of `$.param(data)` given above, and loses information since it doesn't work recursively.

Comment: Have you tried extracting only the source of jquery.param? http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/

Comment: @RicardoCastañeda That might just be the best idea. I had hoped there might be a more straightforward solution. The extracted code from jQuery would just be the perfect answer, and I'd accept it right away ;-) (It would also be a great addition to [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com)). I guess I'll have a look.

Comment: I have added an answer with the code, if that is not the correct source you can edit the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made a quick function for you which should achieve this for you, it will create parameters from your key=>value pairs and stringify your non primitive values.

```
var objToParams = function(obj){
    var paramString = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        var value = obj[key];
        if(obj[key] instanceof Array || obj[key] instanceof Object){
            value = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(value));
        }
        if (paramString != "") paramString += "&";
        paramString += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    return paramString;
}

var data = {"apple": [{"kiwi": "orange"}, {"banana": "lemon"}], "pear": "passion fruit"};
console.log(objToParams(data));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7buy3rjy/

**Edit, from your comment this should work and is now matching the output of $.param:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mg511z7w/

```
var data = {"apple": [{"kiwi": "orange"}, {"banana": "lemon"}], "pear": "passion fruit"};

var stringifyParam = function(data, topLevel, keyProp) {
        var string = '';
        for (var key in data) {
            if(keyProp && topLevel[keyProp] ) {
                if ( (topLevel[keyProp] instanceof Array&&topLevel[keyProp].indexOf(data[key])!==0) ) {
                    string += keyProp;
                } else if ( (topLevel[keyProp] instanceof Object&&topLevel[keyProp][key]) ) {
                    string += keyProp;
                }
            }
            if (typeof(topLevel[key])=='undefined') {
                string += '[' + key + ']';
            }
            if (data[key] instanceof Array) {
                string += stringifyParam(data[key], topLevel, key);
            } else if(data[key] instanceof Object){
                string += stringifyParam(data[key], topLevel, key);            
            } else {
                if (typeof(topLevel[key])!='undefined') {
                    string += key;
                }
                string += '=' + data[key];
                string += '&';
            }
        }
        return string;
    },
    toParam = function(data){
        var string = stringifyParam(data,data);
        return encodeURI(string.substring(0,string.length-1).split(' ').join('+'));
    };

console.log(toParam(data)); //apple%5B0%5D%5Bkiwi%5D=orange&apple%5B1%5D%5Bbanana%5D=lemon&pear=passion+fruit
console.log($.param(data)); //apple%5B0%5D%5Bkiwi%5D=orange&apple%5B1%5D%5Bbanana%5D=lemon&pear=passion+fruit
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, but this doesn't appear to do exactly the right thing. If you append `console.log($.param(data));` at the end of your fiddle (and require jQuery), you will see the output of `$.param` is different. I tried your code, but unfortunately my server chokes if I send it the output from your function.

Comment: love your approach! Very nice code. I just got lazy and fudged my initial answer into what I thought was wanted. :P

Comment: I ended up extracting the jQuery source code, but thanks for this. :) @Todd Sorry if it wasn't entirely clear what I wanted, I thought that "do what `$.param` does" was precise enough, and I tried to give some context, but maybe it ended up being confusing.

Comment: There is a bug in implementation of stringifyParam: 
'if (topLevel[key]) { string += key;  }'
should be replaced by 
'if (topLevel[key] != undefined) { string += key;  }'

Because 0 (zero) is a value! :)

Comment: There's another bug I'm afraid: calling `toParam({var:{foo:"bar",baz:"qux"}});` gets me `var%5Bfoo%5D=bar&%5Bbaz%5D=qux` which decodes to `var[foo]=bar&[baz]=qux`, i.e. the second `var[]` portion is missing.

Comment: Updated the answer with the code that fixed that bug in my case. `toParam({var:{foo:"bar",baz:"qux"}});` now gets me `var[foo]=bar&var[baz]=qux` and `toParam({var:['foo','bar']})` returns `var[0]=foo&var[1]=bar`. Please review.

Comment: My previous edit was rejected. Re-submitting: fixed the following bugs: 1. if an array passed is `{foo:null}` it returned `[foo]` while it should have been `foo=` (this seems like a bug @SergioRykov mentioned); 2. if data contained a multi-level object, it would not repeat the top-level object key.

Answer (score 0):

You could go about doing recursive code but why not try the simple scheme JSON, which was why it was created - To exchange data between client and server in an easier manner.

Just do this

```
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

`JSON.stringify` accepts an Object which will then be converted to a valid JSON, which can be parsed in the server-side.

To know more about the JSON, there can't be a better way than going through it's tag excerpt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about JSON, however unfortunately I am free to modify the client-side code, but I can't modify the server-side code. The server expects a query string instead of a JSON string, so I need a function which converts an objects to a query string, like `$.param` does.

Answer (score 0):

you could use encode and decode URIComponent functions to accomplish this.

## edit

what about this:

```
var qs = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a,k){
    a.push(k+'='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj[k])));
    return a;
},[]).join('&');

// "apple=%5B%7B%22kiwi%22%3A%22orange%22%7D%2C%7B%22banana%22%3A%22lemon%22%7D%5D&pear=%22passion%20fruit%22"
```

instead of this:

```
var obj = {"apple": [{"kiwi": "orange"}, {"banana": "lemon"}], "pear": "passion fruit"};

var data = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));

// "%7B%22apple%22%3A%5B%7B%22kiwi%22%3A%22orange%22%7D%2C%7B%22banana%22%3A%22lemon%22%7D%5D%2C%22pear%22%3A%22passion%20fruit%22%7D"

var obj2 = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(data));

// {"apple":[{"kiwi":"orange"},{"banana":"lemon"}],"pear":"passion fruit"}
```

Comment: Concerning your edit: it's still not the same as `$.param(data)`. As stated above, the expected output would be `apple%5B0%5D%5Bkiwi%5D=orange&apple%5B1%5D%5Bbanana%5D=lemon&pear=passion+fruit` (which is `apple[0][kiwi]=orange&apple[1][banana]=lemon&pear=passion fruit` in URL-decoded form). Your function more or less URL-encodes a JSON string, which is different.